# Why does my car have cold AC at idle, but intermittent on the highway?

Tags: ac, nissan, intermittent-problems

My 2009 Nissan Maxima has cold air when idling, but when I get on the Highway it tends to get warm for a while then it kicks back on to cold. Not sure what the issue is.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to the site. When was the last time the AC system was serviced? It may be as simple as that.

Comment: High pressure low pressure mix up

Answer (score 1):

How long have you had this car? If it's been years and you haven't had the a/c worked on and checked, you might need a full tune-up.  Your possible issues:

1. You drive too hard - the compressor will shut off and blow warmer when you get close to full throttle.
2. Your engine is overheating - the compressor will kick off when a thermal threshold is reached...but it will turn back on when it cools off.
3. The compressor is failing - less likely from what you described, but possible, it will get worse and worse as you use it and usually make a grinding/whirring noise soon.

My bet is # 2), which can include a bit of # 1), if you are low on engine coolant/oil, engine is running poorly because of tune, of A/C needs recharge WITH system lubricant, I won't be surprised. Can you check any of those things yourself? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

High pressure and low pressure issues. Get pressure testing done on the system.